# Json serialization and storage strategy

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, deserialization

Json is often used in web applications. I set a field in the database to text to store json strings. It may not be a good idea to design a database in this way, but my reason is that the composition of the data may be volatile and does not require external connections. Using Json serialization tools such as Newtonsoft can easily de-serialize a json string from a database into a JObject object, but in a static language program, it will definitely require some more concrete objects to express it, and now I'm facing some Optional options:

1. De-serialize the json string from the database to get JObject, then
   use this object directly
2. continue to resolve JObject, instantiate a more specific object A, and then use the object A

Option 1 is very convenient for storage and initialization of the read, but when used to get the value string, error-prone. Scenario 2 requires an extra layer of conversion for storing and initializing reads, but it is more intuitive and convenient to use. I am very tangled about which scheme to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"More intuitive and convenient to use"* is the key here. You should always try to write code in a readable and maintainable way, and if creating model objects for your JSON data helps you achieve this goal, and this doesn't impact performance beyond what's acceptable for your project, do it; the extra conversion layer will be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a reason that you cannot, I would have a concrete dto that your JSON can be de-serialised into. This provides you compile time type safety for all usages (at least after the initial instantiating). I would normally go another step and have a business object class that can instantiate itself from that dto, but that obviously depends on your specific requirements.

On top of type safety, you get a whole bunch more benefits when using a concrete object, but I suspect that at this point I'm preaching to the choir.

One reason you may not be able to is where the content itself is dynamic in nature (and by extension your code expects nothing specific about the JSON string other than maybe that it is well formed). Very few problems are like this though.

So the downside is usually the overhead of the time and effort in writing those concrete classes. Once you have them defined, deserialising them is literally 1 line of code. The trick then is to use a tool to reverse engineer the necessary classes from the JSON string. Due to SO policies, I cannot recommend tools, but if you were to use a search engine that rhymes with frugal and search for something like JSON to c#, you are bound to find a quick way to create those dtos.